# How to configure EU cookie compliance module for only Google Analytics

Tags: cookies

I have installed and configured the [EU cookie compliance](https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance) module, but it only displays the message when I log into admin section. I use [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) and I must show the message for all the site.

I think that the issue is that Drupal doesn't set any cookie and that's why it doesn't display the message (the GA cookie is external to Drupal).

How can show the message when I use only the GA cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the permission page (admin/people/permissions), check "Display EU Cookie Compliance popup" for the anonymous user.